# unable to upload photo using jquery/ajax facebook graph api b'coz of formpost data error 

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

i have a jquery-ajax call to php page that is supposed to upload user photos to users default album;but when call is made error occurs as

> **failed creating formpost data 
>   curl**  **exception**

here is the code of jquery ajax function and php script that uploads user photo:

### jquery-ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "./page1.php",//link to php page
  data: "link=" + lnk, //image path 
  success: function(msg){
                    alert('upd: '+msg);
                },
   error: function(msg){
                    alert('flt: '+msg);
                }

    });
```

### php script (page1.php )

```
$lnk = $_REQUEST['link'];
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$attachement = array(‘access_token’ => $session['access_token'],
‘source’ =>’@’ . realpath($lnk),
 ‘name’ => ‘my ------ friend’,
‘message’ => ‘m pic;get yours at http://apps.facebook.com//‘
);
$fb_photo = $facebook->api(‘me/photos’,'POST’,$attachement);
```

dump of response error :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
> curlException occuring:
> [message:protected] => failed creating
> formpost data [string:private] =>
> [code:protected] => 26
> [line:protected] => 639
> [trace:private] => Array ( [0] =>
> Array (
> 
> [file] =>
> /home/*******/public_html/******/facebook.php [line] => 592 [function] =>
> makeRequest [class] => Facebook [type]
> => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
> [1] => Array (.....
```

please help regarding this;
it will be great;

stuck in this issue;